# How to get Rails app using Rabbit-MQ to trigger Airflow DAG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, airflow

I have a rails application that is triggering a task by writing into a Rabbit-MQ queue.

In Airflow which is setup with Celery and Rabbit-MQ I want to trigger a DAG to run when a message hits the Rabbit-MQ queue.

Is this something that can be done in this way?

Can I write into the Celery/Rabbit-MQ queues from another application? And if so how do I pass parameters.